# What indexes to add to speed up COUNT(*) query with three conditions

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

Here is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`)
FROM `comments`
WHERE
    `user_id` != '1' -- Author does not need to know about his own comments
    AND (
        `article_id` IN (4, 2476, 14954, 83981, 83982)
        OR `request_id` IN (3, 5, 7)
    );
```

And the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `part_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `request_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` text,
  `add_date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `key_article_id_add_date` (`article_id`,`add_date`),
  KEY `key_part_id_add_date` (`part_id`,`add_date`),
  KEY `add_date` (`add_date`),
  KEY `request_id` (`request_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`article_id`,`request_id`)
) ENGINE=innodb AUTO_INCREMENT=3536452 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

No matter how I try and what index I add, mysql perferrs to scan all 3039138 rows and query takes forewer. Here is the EXPLAIN output:

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+--------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys                              | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+--------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | comments | ALL  | key_article_id_add_date,user_id,request_id | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 3039138 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------+--------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

If I remove one of confitions (`user_id`, `article_id` or `request_id`) mysql seems to have no problems using indexes, but with all the 3 of them - nothing helps.

Any ideas how I can index comments table so mysql could use an index on this query? Or is there any other solution to improve this query performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check the current execution plan for this query and identify whether its using the key you have created for those three columns. If it is not using that particular index, then force the sql to use that index like below

```
SELECT Count(`id`)
FROM   `comments` USE INDEX (user_id_corresponding_index_name)
WHERE  `user_id` != '1'
       -- Author does not need to know about his own comments    
       AND ( `article_id` IN ( 4, 2476, 14954, 83981, 83982 )
              OR `request_id` IN ( 3, 5, 7 ) );
```

Please replace user_id_corresponding_idex_name with corresponding name of non-clustered index created for user_id key in your table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/index-hints.html

Comment: @silverLight did you try this approach?

Comment: USE INDEX did not seem to work for me, but FORCE INDEX (described on the same manual page) did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

adding index on any column that you are using in where clause doesnt gurantee its usage or fastness. it depends on the volume of data and the dbms impl logic. but in general any column that you are querying with where clause on, adding a index on it would help.

in this you would want to add index on all three columns (user_id, article_id or request_id)

Comment: I already have a `KEY user_id (user_id,article_id,request_id)` which seems to make no difference...